# Grails update one to many from the parent domain model

Tags: grails

I am updating a one to many from the parent domain model in a controller.

The code looks like this:

```
def update() {

   def parentInstance = Parent.get(params.id)

   params.childerenDetails.each {

      parentInstance.addToChildrens(
         newChildren(
            name:params.get(name_"${it}"),
            age:params.get(age_"${it}"))
      }
   }

   if(parentInstance.validate()) {
      parentInstance.save(flush:true)
   } else {
      render "error found at"+parentInstance.errors
   }
}
```

....here I have custom validation in Parent class when adding the children values getting that parent validation error but children objects are saving into the db ..how to prevent if validation error comes in parent domain

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent children to be stored into the DB you need to either move this code into a `Service`, which is transactional by default, or encapsulate all the code inside a `Parent.withTransaction { // }`. If you choose to use the service you can throw a `RuntimeException` when you detect the validation error to force a rollback. If you use the `withTransaction`, you can manually rollback it with `status.setRollbackOnly`:

```
def parentInstance = Parent.get(params.id)
Parent.withTransaction { status ->
   params.childerenDetails.each {

     parentInstance.addToChildrens(
        newChildren(
           name:params.get(name_"${it}"),
           age:params.get(age_"${it}"))
       }
   }

   if(parentInstance.validate()) {
      parentInstance.save(flush:true)
   } else {
     status.setRollbackOnly()
   }
}
```

Not sure if a `parentInstance.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` would trigger a rollback as well.
I would prefer though to move the business logic to a Service. See [withTransaction](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withTransaction.html) and [Services](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html) docs in the Ref Guide.